# HTML/CSS - What is name of this menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

What is name of this drop down menu found at http://bit.ly/NHDSSH

When you hover over "Products" and then hover over for example "Hand pallet trucks", there will be shown submenu that I'm looking for.

Does it even have a name? Similar script would be fine as well :)

Comment: There isn't always a ready made script for everything. This should be reasonably easy to write yourself, although personally I find the menu quite annoying.

Comment: Of course I will write one myself, if I don't find some ready made script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source it looks like the menu uses the RadControl toolset, which my quick searching reveals that it's an ASP.NET (and maybe others) toolset that doesn't seem to use jQuery.

Based on the functionality on that page, the vertical menu is sliding down and then the horizontal sub-menu, which starts off hidden and with a negative left position is animated by sliding left to `left:0`.

I would describe it as *horizontal sliding submenu*.

Closest starting point I could find is http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jMenu/demo but you would definitely need to customise it to slideLeft instead of down on the submenu.

Comment: Thank you. I used superfish menu, and I had to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google should provide tons of menus for you, here's the first on the list:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: Please read my question again. I think that I was clear. I'm looking for a name of such drop down menu (if is any). Secondly but not that important is ready made exact script (again if is any). If is not, I'll made one myself, no problem there. Btw. I know to use search engine, I already was on page that you posted (and similar ones) and I was unable to find exact drop down menu. Hope I'm clear now.